# Copying 'b' instruction at runtime doesn't work

Tags: assembly, mips

here is my test code:

```
.data
msg:        .asciiz     "test\n"

.text

partc:
b       partb

parta:
syscall

partb:
la      $a0, msg
li      $v0, 4
syscall
li      $v0, 10
syscall

_start:
main:

lw      $t0, partc
la      $t1, parta
sw      $t0, ($t1)
b       parta
```

If I run the code as is, it gives memory out of bound error. However, if I change `b` to `j` in `partc`, it works fine. I know that `j` can jump further than `b` but I thought it was the only difference between them. What is the problem here?

Comment: Note that self-modifying code on MIPS may need to invalidate the instruction cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` uses relative address, `j` uses absolute address. As such, if you copy a `b` from one place to another, it will not jump to the originally intended address, rather it will jump the same distance from the new location.